# query on RFID tags

Tags: java, rfid

I am trying to integrate my software(developed in java) with a rifd reader.The data read by the reader when a card was swiped is 0068276206 and when the same card was swiped on fingerprint system with a reader it displayed the card number as 0001167342.
     To get the value(0068276206) i read the data into a byte array(using java io) and got the ascii equivalent. When i tried a different make card which is also a ISO card both systems showed the same value.I even tried reversing each byte but it dint work too.
     Does any one know the solution or have faced the same problem.I am doing any thing wrong??

Comment: Hi, sorry for this comment which doesn't help, but I'm interested in the subject, especialy how to write data on cards, what hardware, and operating system etc ...
But I didn't find your email.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So basically you're saying that the first type of card returned a different number for your rfid then your fingerprint system and that the second type of card did return the same number in both systems.

Could it be that the first type of card contains different numbers for fingerprint and rfid?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so.I found 1 more difference the difference between the rfid reaer-fingerprint reader is 67108864.which is 2 power of 26.What i feel is the reader is reading a bit which it should ideally neglet.does any one know abt it,.